# Kubuntu 16.04 GUI not working, goes straight to terminal login

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, login, gui

I recently updated to Kubuntu version 16.04 from version 14.04 after getting the upgrade notification.  It successfully downloaded and installed, but after rebooting the system, it went straight to a terminal login screen.  Even after successfully logging in, the GUI doesn't auto-load.

Comment: can you get the GUI to start by pressing ctrl+alt+F7? Or by typing the command `startx`?

Comment: I tried  ctrl+alt+F7 first and that just sent me to a black screen, but the `startx` command did launch the GUI after I logged in on the terminal. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you have to do that every time, or do you get a normal GUI login screen now?

Comment: @Tornado118 have you tried the answer given?

Comment: I apologize for being so long in getting back. Yes Zanna, I have to type it every time I restart the system.

Answer (score 4):

While you're on terminal after boot, install `sddm`.

```
sudo apt-get install sddm
```

This will install the required display manager for KDE and you'll be presented with graphical login after reboot.

Comment: I did this but it said that it was already installed.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to give a working solution but I had the same issue. I'm in the progess of going 14.04 -> 16.04 -> 18.04. (Seems like that last update only becomes available when 18.04.1 is released.)
I was able to fix it by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

This command didn't show any output though.

Found it here: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/70629-Kubuntu-16-04-does-not-start-up-to-GUI

Comment: thank you for your reply; although I can't confirm whether or not this fixes the issue for me due to the fact that I reverted back to windows on the pc I was having this issue on, and got myself a new laptop on which I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04.  Thank you for the reply nontheless!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a file located under `~/.Xauthority` remove that file `rm ~/.Xauthority` then start your machine `sudo reboot`